# Offset world coordinates three js

Tags: three.js, coordinates, offset

Is there a way to offset the world coordinates in three.js? I want to translate the center(0,0,0) by some value so the center will be at the center of my div element.

Comment: add a translation transform to your scene hierarchy.

Comment: How can i do it?Can you lead me to some example or site?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a translation transform to your `scene` hierarchy.

```
scene.position.set( x, y, z );
```

But if you have only one object hanging of your `scene` you should apply the transform there.